# What are our limitations on spinning a baseball sized 5 kg sphere to really fast speeds?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

I know the limitation of the ball being able to hold itself together, lets assume that would not be an issue. If we were to apply a constant force over long enough time would anything short of the speed of light be possible?

Are there limitations in our technology for magnetically spinning it up similar to an electric motor?

Comment: If strength of the material is not an issue then I don't see any fundamental physical problem with spinning a ball to relativistic speeds. See, for example: "Monster black hole spins at half the speed of light",  http://earthsky.org/science-wire/monster-black-hole-spins-at-half-the-speed-of-light . If you were to try to spin, say, a baseball-sized steel sphere to relativistic speeds, I would bet that it would fly apart long before you reached such speeds due to the finite yield strength of steel.

Comment: If you have a fraction of a million to spare you can buy an ultracentrifuge which does just that. The highest rim speed that you can achieve will be close to the speed of sound in the material, though.

Comment: Space-time dragging?

Comment: @CuriousOne is "rim speed close to speed of sound" a limit you can calculate, or just "how it works in practice"?

Comment: @Floris: Some first or second semester experimental physics phenomenology that I carry around with me without the slightest regard for theory, if you don't mind. For my taste it's enough to know what I can and can not do. If I want to make an engineering problem out of these things, I look them up in the textbooks. +1 for your precise answer, though.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm totally fine with "just stuff you know". And I realize it's a good rule of thumb. I was just curious whether there was something deep going on that I didn't immediately get. And thanks for the +.

Comment: @Floris: Do I think of continuum mechanics as a deep and dark hole that swallowed my grades? Yes. I think I did better in every single class than in continuum mechanics. Even in general relativity... and I really, really didn't have a clue what the heck I was doing there. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the object spins faster, you will need a higher drive frequency to continue to apply torque. At the size of a baseball, circumference is about 9.25 inches (let's say 25 cm). To rotate the surface at the speed of light would imply 1.2 GHz . At that frequency, the skin depth for steel is about 1.2 um, implying very high resistivity which would lead to high heat dissipation and low torque. At any rate, the tensile forces would have ripped it apart a long time before you got to that speed.

Although you stipulated "a material strong enough", let's do a bit of math:

The hoop stress for a disk is greatest at the center, and given by

$$\sigma = (3+\nu)\frac{\rho\omega^2R^2}{8}$$

With the yield stress of diamond equal to about 60 GPa (a pretty good upper limit for a "real" material) and density of steel around 8000 kg/m$^3$, we get $\omega \lt 100,000$ and a frequency less than about 16 kHz.

That gives a rim speed of 4000 m/s (note - much faster than the speed of sound in steel because I was using the strength of diamond...). Note that the stress goes with velocity squared - to go up by about five orders of magnitude would require material that is ten orders of magnitude stronger than diamond. The energy of the bond would have to reflect this - for diamond it's about 3.6 eV, so you would need bond energy of around 3.6 MeV. You can't make that with electrons... Maybe a baby black hole?

Of course as you approach the speed of light your mass would increase and other terrible things would happen - all conspiring to doom the experiment to failure.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, most accreting black holes seem to be rotating near the theoretical maximum... not sure that qualifies as a matter based "sphere", though.

Comment: Ha - so my "baby black hole" might have had something going for it... thanks.

Comment: My intuition about extremal black holes fits on the tip of a needle, where it likes dancing with the other angels... :-)

Comment: Plenty of space for my intuition regarding anything to do with relativity then.

Comment: Black holes are not an attractive system for the experimentalist who likes to be hands on... well, strictly speaking, neither is the interior of a running ultracentrifuge.

Comment: With black holes, I thought "hands on" isn't the problem. Hands "off again" - that's another story.

Comment: I admit that experiments that prevent me from ever publishing the paper bother me somewhat...

Answer (score 3):

For a smaller object you can do a bit better

"Dr Yoshihiki Arita, Dr Michael Mazilu and Professor Kishan Dholakia of the School of Physics and Astronomy at the University of St Andrews were able to levitate and spin a microscopic sphere, purely using laser light in a vacuum, briefly up to 600 million RPM before it broke apart."

http://phys.org/news/2013-08-fastest-rotating-man-made.html

Comment: People spin protons at even higher rates in high field NMR... And they don't break. Even smaller objects. That $R^2$ term...